# WPF: How to get Radiobuttons to display as a horizontal row of ToggleButtons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm currently building a UI that is going to be used in a touch panel. Therefore, I would like to display any RadioButton groups as horizontal rows of ToggleButtons. I already figured out how to display ToggleButtons instead of the standard bullet items:

```
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type RadioButton}" 
           TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
```

However, this will show a **column** of ToggleButtons, not a **row**.
Do you know an easy way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out: the RadioButtons are not involved in the solution - I had to modify the ItemsControl that hosted them:

```
<Style x:Key="myKey" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 15):

Put radio buttons in a StackPanel with Orientation set to Horizontal.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <RadioButton Content="1"/>
   <RadioButton Content="2"/>
   <RadioButton Content="3"/>
</StackPanel >
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I did a similar thing in my style definition :-)